# how to setup subdomains for pages?

Tags: pages, subdomains

how can I give specific subdomains to my pages like mypage.example.com instead of example.com/mypage already tried all plugins available but no results also manually created a subdirectory for the subdomain and put an index.php and included the page id too... every time it just redirected me to the main domain
any idea how to do that?

Comment: If you are using multi-site then you have to add `define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);` .

Comment: already try that! but its just redirect me to the same directory.